# Convert excel 2007 to excel 2003

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

According to my scenario, I want to convert Excel 2007 (.xlsx) file to  Excel 2003 (.xls).

I want to to this with C# code.

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert xlsx files into 2003 xls files programatically in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806771/how-to-convert-xlsx-files-into-2003-xls-files-programatically-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution with Excel 2007+**

In Excel 2007, click on the `Office Button` > `Save As...`

Then, change the format to `.xls` (Excel Workbook 97 - 2003).

**Solution without any Excel version >2003**

See [this article](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2007/10/open-xlsx-spreadsheet-files-without.html)

**Solution through VBA**

[Way to convert from .xls to .xlsm via a batch file or vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167207/way-to-convert-from-xls-to-xlsm-via-a-batch-file-or-vba/7172031#7172031)

**[EDIT] Solution with C#**

[How to convert xlsx files into 2003 xls files programatically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806771/how-to-convert-xlsx-files-into-2003-xls-files-programatically-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

Open the Excel 2007 file in Office 2007 and simply, Click on Top Left Ms-Office log
and select Save as arrow button not on Save as option and then select Excel 97-2003 
option.....It Will Definitely Work For You.

Comment: Sorry I missed a line in my Question ... I want to to this with C sharp code !!!!

Comment: @Saqlain Raza Hemani: see my edited answer and have a look at [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)